# Remove dynamic username from file path

Tags: c#, regex, filepath

I have the following in C#.

```
string fileName = @"X:\Users\username\AppData\Local\foo.txt";
```

I want to perform a `Regex.Replace` so that I get the following back.

```
string fileName = @"X:\Users\AppData\Local\foo.txt";
```

It would be nice to use a Regex that allows for the drive letter (`X:`) to be dynamic. In essence, I just need to drop the '`username`' part. Also, note that username is just a placeholder for the user's actual name - so that could be bob or larry or john or anything else. The Regex will need to take this into account.

The thing that you can count on here is that it will always start with `X:\Users\` (where X: can be `C:` or `D:`, etc.) and then will be followed with some string and then will be followed by a `\` and then some other path elements that are not important. Also, it would be good to have a case-insensitive match on `users or Users`.

I know that this can be done without `Regex`, but I need this to fit into a larger system that only provides `Regex` support. There's no support for things like `String.Replace` or `String.Join`.

Comment: just split('\') and remove the 2nd item from the array,Done .

Comment: That 's even worse than using a regex...

Comment: `fileName = fileName.Replace(@"\username", "");` would do it, but why you need to use regex ?

Comment: Sorry, but username is dynamic also - it could be john or larry or bob or anything else. I really need to use Regex - I know, it's overkill, but that's okay.

Comment: @Raymond, you keep saying that you need to use Regex. Why is that? It seems like an odd requirement.

Comment: It's part of a larger system - the system itself doesn't provide support for things like string.Replace or string.Join - it only provides support for Regex replacements. Think lowest common denominator. :)

Comment: What exactly are the requirements here? Do you know the username before you do this? do you need to edit the `second word after the drive letter`? How exactly do you know what to replace in your string?

Comment: I don't know the user name ahead of time. I know that there's some "word" after the first backslash and that is followed by another backslash. The word length for the "user name" is variable and the drive letter is variable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "no support"... You can write code without using the `System` namespace?

Comment: @Bob - the expression is stored in XML and evaluated by C# code. The point is that a user configures the expression and the "engine" does the work. The engine only provides support for Regex - not string.Replace, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this sample:

```
string fileName = @"X:\Users\username\AppData\Local\foo.txt";
Console.Write(Regex.Replace(fileName, @"([A-Z]{1}\:*\\Users\\)(\w+\\)(.*)", "$1$3"));
```

Explanation:

1. `([A-Z]{1}\:\\[Uu]sers\\)` - this part of Regex is a first group of characters, before the `username`, in the path

   - `^` stands for the start of the line **(remove this to ignore words preceding the filename)**
   - `[A-Z]{1}\:\\` stands for the disk root path. You can choose the disk letters you want to be here, like this: `[CDX-Z]{1}`. Note `{1}` - this is constraint means you need only 1 uppercase letter.
   - `[Uu]sers\\` stands for the users directory name, note the group for the case-insensitive users path
     This is first group, refered as `$1` in the replace pattern
2. `(\w+\\)` - this part of Regex is a second group of characters, the `username`, in the path

   - `\w+\\` stands for at least one word character and `\` sign.
     This is a second group, which is not in a replace pattern
3. `(.*)` - this part of Regex is a third group of characters, after the `username`, in the path

   - `.*` stands for any character after the removed `\` symbol.

Update:
In the real world I found usernames with spaces, unicode chars and ~ in it. So I replaced the 2. group to include any characters but the `\` sign.

```
string fileName = @"X:\Users\username\AppData\Local\foo.txt";
Console.Write(Regex.Replace(fileName, @"([A-Z]{1}\:\\[Uu]sers\\)([^\\]*\\)(.*)", "$1$3"));
```

Comment: How can I tweak this to ignore words preceding the filename?

string filename = @"This file X:\Users\username\foo.txt is text."

I want to ignore "This file", although that's just an example. Thanks!

Comment: @Raymond Parsons Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you...I figured it out through a bit of research. Really appreciate it.